# How to multiply and Sum 2 columns of datatables using jquery? - Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datatables

**I want to show the result by using JQuery**

I'm using [dataTables](http://datatables.net) library for table to show the result. I want to apply following computation on 2 columns using datatables jquery or ajax like

I have two arrays `var arr1 = [2,3,4,5];` and `var arr2 = [4,3,3,1];`

```
(4*2+3*3+4*3+5*1) Total=34
```

Using DataTables for this table

This is the pic of table result format i want to show like.

[image: I want total like this using jquer]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var t = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
      "searchable": false,
      "orderable": false,
      "targets": 0
    }],
    "order": [
      [1, 'asc']
    ]
  });

  t.on('order.dt search.dt', function() {
    t.column(0, {
      search: 'applied',
      order: 'applied'
    }).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
      cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
    });
  }).draw();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table width="100%" class="display" cellspacing="0" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>NSP</th>
      <th>Current Sales</th>
      <th>Closing Balance</th>
      <th>Current Sales * 1.5</th>
      <th>(-) Closing Balance</th>
      <th>Current Order</th>
      <th>Distributor</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you’re talking about

Comment: i m using this "https://datatables.net"  for table to show the result. I want to apply this formula on these 2 columns using datatables jquery or ajax like i have two arrays var arr1 = [2,3,4,5];
var arr2 = [4,3,3,1];  "(4*2+3*3+4*3+5*1)  Total=34"

Comment: Feel free to edit your question

Comment: @AhsanNajam whatever you are asking is not matching with the code that you shared. I'm not able to infer from where you are getting table data. Please provide necessary code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashantpokhriyal/9qLdLnxs/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // multiply nsp and closing balance
  $.each(dataSet, function(i, row) {
    row.total = row.nsp * row.closing_balance;
  });


  // Table definition
  var dtapi = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    "deferRender": false,
    "footerCallback": function(tfoot, data, start, end, display) {
      var api = this.api();
      // adding product of nsp and closing_balance
      // here column 5 contains product so change it
      // accordingly
      var p = api.column(5).data().reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
      }, 0)
      $(api.column(5).footer()).html(p);
      $("#total").val(p);
    },
    "order": [1],
    "columns": [

      // rest of the columns
      {
        data: "id"
      }, {
        data: "product_name"
      }, {
        data: "nsp"
      }, {
        data: "closing_balance",
      }, {
        data: "date",
      }, {
        data: "total"
      }

    ]
  });
});

// DataTable data set used
var dataSet = [{
  "id": "Airi",
  "product_name": "Satou",
  "nsp": 230,
  "closing_balance": 23,
  "date": "28th Nov 08",
}, {
  "id": "Angelica",
  "product_name": "Ramos",
  "nsp": "191",
  "closing_balance": 131,
  "date": "9th Oct 09",
}, {
  "id": "Ashton",
  "product_name": "Cox",
  "nsp": 191,
  "closing_balance": 37,
  "date": "12th Jan 09",
}];
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table class="display" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>NSP</th>
      <th>Closing Balance</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>NSP * Closing Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>NSP</th>
      <th>Closing Balance</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>NSP * Closing Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<label>Total</label>
<input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" readonly value="0.0" />
```

Comment: Sorry i have little confussion, i don't know how to use data or this column data, is there any simple way to show that rowTotal values in <td> like i call values from database of closing balance <td><?php echo $row['closing-balance']; ?></td>

Comment: from data you mean `dataSet`?

Comment: yes i want to show "NSP * Closing Balance" list in table. i don't know how to use data

Comment: Did you run above code snippet? If so then you can clearly see that I'm priting `NSP * Closing Balance` as a separate column

Comment: Thank You Prashant for this effort. But still my confusion is i don't know how to use dataSet, So how can i apply directly to the specific table column values. Like if i apply to <td class="total"></td>  I hope u understand my question. Sorry i m new to programming.